# Export Excel and Chart data into excel

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a table(country,city,state,orderid,etc) and i have bar chart with profit for each city in ssrs report.

I want to export the report into excel like:

1. First sheet should have the table
2. from 2nd sheet to nth sheet, i want to display each country's data in the table along with bar chart.

eg: in 2nd sheet we need to have India's data in the table and
bar chart should show cities data residing in India.

Thanks